# How to create an image using images with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, image-processing

How to create an image using images with FFMPEG? Something like below?

```
-f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1080x1920 -loop 1 -i 1.png -loop 1 -i 2.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0[v1];[v1][2:v]overlay=shortest=1:x=10:y=10 -vframes 1 -q:v 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out by myself

```
-f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1080x1920 -loop 1 -i 1.png -loop 1 -i 2.png -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0[v1];[v1][2:v]overlay=shortest=1:x=10:y=10 -r 1 -vframes 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 export.jpg
```